# Formatting Error Message

Tags: php

I am trying to format a error message when the login details are incorrect. I would like it in a red panel along the top of the screen. I cant find any help on this anywhere.
Thank you in advance

```
header("Location: login.php?msg=You have entered the Login details incorrectly");
//echo "Error:";
```

Comment: `login.php` will have to check `if($_GET['msg'])` exists and act accordingly.

Comment: Creating a flashbag, would be better then passing back the error.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone If OP doesn't know how to use `$_GET`, they should probably start with baby steps first.

Comment: @ceejayoz true, seems like MasterOfCoding has covered it.

Answer (score 1):

As ceejayoz said `login.php` will have to check `if($_GET['msg'])` exists and act accordingly.

Try adding on `login.php`:

```
<?php

if(!isset($_GET['msg'])) {
    echo "<div style='background: red; padding: 1em; display: table;'>" . $_GET['msg'] . "</div>";
}

?>
```

Also, Using `$_SESSION[]` would be better, So the user cannot change the message in the url, Try Using:

```
$_SESSION['msg'] = "You have entered the Login details incorrectly";
header("Location: login.php");
```

And add this on `login.php` page:

```
<?php
// if got message to show
if (isset($_SESSION['msg'])) {
    echo "<div style='background: red; padding: 1em; display: table;'>" . $_SESSION['msg'] . "</div>";
    unset($_SESSION['msg']); // unset to show once
}

?>
```

`$_GET[]` and `$_SESSION[]` are both super Global variables,

Super Global documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php